# Storing and retrieving objects of unknown type without casts

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Given:

Object of class A contains an array of objects.

Each of these objects must implement some interface IB, because A use methods of IB.

These objects are passed to object of class A by client, and they are of type C or its children. A must return these objects back to clients.

Problem: A must not know anything about C, only about IB, but A must return C.

Is there any standard solution in C++ without unsafe casts<>?

Comment: Sounds like you've spent too much time writing Java. C++ has no notion of an "interface" separate from a `class`. As such, IB must be a class, and A can simply return a (pointer|reference) to an IB. C must (apparently) derive from IB, but A doesn't need to know that.

Comment: This answer may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950711/conversion-from-subclass-to-superclass-to-subclass/7950896#7950896

Comment: You say *unsafe casts<>* as if `static_cast` etc are unsafe. They're perfectly safe if you use them right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with `A` not knowing *anything* about `C`.  However, having `A` know enough to use the right interface is not that hard in C++.  Have all classes with `IB` derive from a single abstract base class with the interface defined there as pure virtual functions.  This actually corresponds to proper C++ design--separating interface from implementation--as described in e.g. [Sutter & Alexandrescu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586).

Otherwise, if the above really is impossible, you could make `A` a template class, and store the array elements as `void*`, resolving the class type (at compile time) using `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a perfectly safe class using templates.

```
template  <typename T>class A
{
    std::vector<IB*> myObj;

public:


    void add(IB* anObj)
    {
        myObj.push_back(anObj);
    }

    void get(int anIndex, T*& anObj)
    {
        T* t = dynamic_cast<T*>(myObj[anIndex]);
        anObj = t;
    }
};
```

And then use like this.

```
A<C> a;
```

Demo is given [here](http://codepad.org/2It3PLSN)